# Clickhouse Instalation: unable to locate package

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, clickhouse

I'm trying to install Clickhouse on my ubuntu 14.04 server.

I've configured sources.list with yandex repo/

```sh
    deb http://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/trusty stable main
```

I've run `sudo apt-get update`

And I've ended up with this error.

```sh
    user@server:# sudo apt-get install clickhouse-client clickhouse-server-common
    Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done
    E: Unable to locate package clickhouse-client
    E: Unable to locate package clickhouse-server-common
```

What's wrong?

Comment: use docker image instead https://hub.docker.com/r/yandex/clickhouse-server/

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys E0C56BD4
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install clickhouse-client clickhouse-server-common
```

if key expired
use

```
wget -q -O - https://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/CLICKHOUSE-KEY.GPG | apt-key add -
```

Comment: I'm running 32-bit ubuntu version. 64-bit version is required for clickhouse,  I've missed that part.

Answer (score 1):

quote https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/getting_started/install/

It is recommended to use official pre-compiled deb packages for Debian or Ubuntu.

To install official packages add the Yandex repository in /etc/apt/sources.list or in a separate /etc/apt/sources.list.d/clickhouse.list file:

```
  deb http://repo.clickhouse.tech/deb/stable/ main/
```